# TTL in an RF switch

Tags: power-supply, ttl, testbench

I am hoping to find help on how to properly connect supply voltage to my switch assembly in order to actuate.  My switch has input requirement of +15, -15, GND, and +5V.  Also, the 5v logic inputs. High ON, low OFF.

Can +15, -15, GND come from the same supply.  My bench model has 3 terminal.  Can the +5V and TTL use the same supply?  Since I need multiple supplies do they share same GND reference?

[image: schematic]

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please edit your question and add a schematic. Otherwise, you're asking people to draw this in their heads. Please don't post a giant photo of a sketch. The schematic editor here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Thanks.

Comment: Which switch assembly? Generally, +5V = TTL, and all of the grounds are shared.  But without knowing *exactly* what the switch assembly is, this could be wrong.

Comment: My application is a custom assembly that has multiple switches inside one module.  I provide assembly service and wish to verify functionality with a continuity check.  I will try the schematic editor per TonyM's suggestion.

Comment: Hi!  I could not find the editor here, but instead used an online tool.  https://tinyurl.com/yyhvlczk.  I was not sure if 3 supplies were needed.  The TTL input is indeed +5V